What is the yaml equivalent of the jq root .[]
I'm pulling data and can refer to a child of the root:
variables:
  - something
parameters:
  - else
...
...

I don't want to call variables or parameters individually, I want to pull the entire object from the root level.

Do you want to use yq for operate with the YAML file? According to that question, that utility refers the root by using . notation, in the same way as jq refers root of JSON.
